# Determine when dojo dijit dialog and all widgets have completed first load/populate

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

Ok, I have what may be seem like a very dumb question to many of you, but I'm stumped.  I'm working on a somewhat dated dojo project.  Part of it has been converted to AMD and part hasn't.  This part hasn't, so please bear with me.

I have a page that loads with a dgrid and has the shell of a dijit.Dialog built but hidden in html markup.  There is a edit button on the page that when pressed, builds and populates the dialog and it's associated dijits (Selects, multiselects, etc. via old dojox.data.XmlStores and uses the data from the selected grid row to select the correct data in each dijit.  As the dijits are built, onChange events are added. when the data is set in these dijits, the onChange events fire.  This is needed.  Sometimes one dijit's value needs to change another dijit's value...even on the first load. However, I have a couple extra javascript funtions that are tied to onChange events and set values of fields based on other values on the page. These DO NOT need to run on the first full load of the dialog and all its fields.

Here's what I think are the relevant pieces of my code:
The HTML markup:

```
<div class="dijitHidden">
             <div data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog" style="width:800px;text-align:left;" id="editDialog">
                <table width='800px' cellpadding='25px' cellspacing='10px'>
                   <tr>
                     <td align="right"><From: </td>
                     <td align="left">
                       <div id="fromSelector"></div>
                     </td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td align="right">Unit: </td>
                     <td align="left">
                       <div id="fromUnitSelector"></div>
                     </td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td align="right">Room: </td>
                     <td align="left">
                       <div id="fromRoomSelector"></div>
                     </td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td align="right">Mode: </td>
                     <td align="left" id="mode">
                       <div id="modeSelector"></div>
                     </td>
                     <td align="right">Priority:</td>
                     <td align="left" id="priority">
                       <div id="prioritySelector"></div>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td align="right">Transporters: </td>
                     <td align="left" id="numSel">
                       <div id="numTranSelector"></div>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td align="right">Type: </td>
                     <td align="left" id="type">
                       <div id="typeSelector"></div>
                     </td>
                     <td align="right">Comments:</td>
                     <td align="left" id="comment">
                       <div id="comments"></div>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                 </table>
             </div>
         </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function edit_button_pressed() {
//Javascript that creates the boxes
            //begin From Location
            dojo.byId("fromSelector").innerHTML = "";
            var fromSelector = dojo.byId("fromSelector");
            var locStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
              url: 'getlocations.url',
              label: 'label',
              keyAttribute:'id'  
            });   
             function sizeLocs(size, request){
                var requests = size;
                if (requests > 0) { 
                  //from
                  var fromSelect = new dijit.form.Select({
                      name: "fromSelect",
                      id: "fromSelect",
                      store: locStore,
                      style: "width: 200px;",
                      labelAttr: "label"
                   }).placeAt(fromSelector);
                  fromSelect.startup();
                  fromSelect.addOption({label: '--Select a Loc--', value: ' '});
                  if (transFromLoc.length > 0) {
                    fromSelect.set('value', transFromLoc);
                  } else {
                    fromSelect.set('value', ' ');
                  }
                  if (disableBecauseStarted) {
                      fromSelect.set('disabled', 'disabled');
                  }
                  fromSelect.on("change", function(){
                      if ((String(fromSelect.value) != String(defaultOrigination)) || disableBecauseStarted) {
                          dijit.byId('fromUnitSelect').set('disabled', 'disabled');
                          dijit.byId('fromRoomSelect').set('disabled', 'disabled');  
                      } else {
                          dijit.byId('fromUnitSelect').set('disabled', false);
                          dijit.byId('fromRoomSelect').set('disabled', false);
                      }
                      setAutoPriority();
                  })
                }
            }        
            //end from location


            //Units Select
            var unitStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
              url: 'getUnits.url',
              label: 'label',
              keyAttribute:'id'  
            });
            //from
            var fromUnitSelect = new dijit.form.Select({
                      name: "fromUnitSelect",
                      id: "fromUnitSelect",
                      store: unitStore,
                      style: "width: 150px;",
                      labelAttr: "label"
                   }).placeAt(dojo.byId('fromUnitSelector'));
            fromUnitSelect.startup();
            fromUnitSelect.set('disabled', 'disabled'); 
            fromUnitSelect.addOption({label: '--Unit--', value: ' '});
            if (transFromUnit.length > 0) {
                fromUnitSelect.set('value', transFromUnit);
            } else {
                fromUnitSelect.set('value', ' ');
            }
            fromUnitSelect.on("change", function(){
                dijit.byId('fromRoomSelect').destroy();
                var fromRoomStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
                  url: 'getRooms.url?UNIT=' + this.value,
                  label: 'label',
                  keyAttribute:'id' 
                });
                var fromRoomSelect = new dijit.form.Select({
                      name: "fromRoomSelect",
                      id: "fromRoomSelect",
                      store: fromRoomStore,
                      style: "width: 150px;",
                      labelAttr: "label"
                   }).placeAt(dojo.byId('fromRoomSelector'));
                fromRoomSelect.startup();
                fromRoomSelect.addOption({label: '--Select a Room--', value: ' '});
                if (transFromRoom.length > 0) {
                    fromRoomSelect.set('value', transFromRoom);
                } else {
                    fromRoomSelect.set('value', ' ');
                }
                if (String(dijit.byId('fromSelect').value) != String(defaultOrigination)) {
                    dijit.byId('fromUnitSelect').set('disabled', 'disabled');
                    dijit.byId('fromRoomSelect').set('disabled', 'disabled');  
                } else {
                    dijit.byId('fromUnitSelect').set('disabled', false);
                    dijit.byId('fromRoomSelect').set('disabled', false);
                }
                if (dijit.byId('patientSelect') != null
                    && String(dijit.byId('patientSelect').value).length > 1 ) {
                    var patientDataStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
                        url: 'getPatient.url?MRN=' + String(dijit.byId('patientSelect').value),
                        rootItem: "patient" 
                     });
                    var getPat = function(items, request){
                      for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                        var item = items[i];
                        var assignedRoom = String(patientDataStore.getValue(item, "assignedRoom"));
                        var reservationRoom = String(patientDataStore.getValue(item, "roomReservationRoom"));
                      }
                      if (reservationRoom.length > 0 ) {
                          setAssToRoom(reservationRoom);
                          setAssRoom(assignedRoom);
                      } else {
                          setAssToRoom(assignedRoom);
                          setAssRoom(assignedRoom);
                      }
                    }
                    var request = patientDataStore.fetch({query:{}, onComplete: getPat});
                }
                setAutoPriority();
            })


        //Begin Modes
            dojo.byId("createModeSelector").innerHTML = "";
            var createModeSelector = dojo.byId("createModeSelector");
            var transModeStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
              url: '/workassign/getTransModes.wa',
              label: 'label',
              keyAttribute:'id'  
            });   
             function transSizeMode(size, request){
                var requests = size;
                var modeSelect = "";
                if (requests > 0) { 
                  createModeSelect = new dijit.form.Select({
                      name: "createModeSelect",
                      id: "createModeSelect",
                      store: transModeStore,
                      style: "width: 200px;",
                      labelAttr: "label"
                   }).placeAt(createModeSelector);
                  createModeSelect.startup();
                  createModeSelect.addOption({label: '--Select a Mode--', value: ' '});
                }
            }
            transModeStore.fetch({query: {}, onBegin: transSizeMode, start: 0, count: 0});   
        //End Modes

        //Begin Types
            dojo.byId("typeSelector").innerHTML = "";
            var typeSelector = dojo.byId("typeSelector");
            var transTypeStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
              url: 'getType.url',
              label: 'label',
              keyAttribute:'id'  
            });   
            var typeSel = new dijit.form.MultiSelect({
                   name: 'typeSelect',
                   id: 'typeSelect',
                   style: 'width: 200px; font-size: 18px;'
                }).placeAt(typeSelector);
            var fillTypes = function(items, request){
                dojo.forEach(items, function(item) {
                var c = dojo.doc.createElement('option');
                c.innerHTML = transTypeStore.getValue(item, "label");
                c.value = transTypeStore.getValue(item, "id");
                typeSelect.appendChild(c);
                })
                if (transType.length > 0) {
                  var transArray = transType.split(",");
                  typeSel.set('value', transArray);
                } else {
                  typeSel.set("value", " ");
                }  
            }
            typeSel.on("change", function(){
                setAutoPriority();
                setAutoTransporters();
            })
            typeSel.startup();       
        //End Types

            dojo.byId("prioritySelector").innerHTML = "";
            var prioritySelector = dojo.byId("prioritySelector");
            var priorityModeStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
              url: 'getPriorities.url',
              label: 'label',
              keyAttribute:'id' 
            });   
             function prioritySizeMode(size, request){
                var requests = size;
                var modeSelect = "";
                if (requests > 0) { 
                  prioritySelect = new dijit.form.Select({
                      name: "prioritySelect",
                      id: "prioritySelect",
                      store: priorityModeStore,
                      style: "width: 200px;",
                      labelAttr: "label"
                   }).placeAt(prioritySelector);
                  prioritySelect.startup();
                  prioritySelect.addOption({label: '--Select a Priority--', value: ' '});
                }
                if (priorityType.length > 0) {
                    prioritySelect.set('value', priorityType);
                } else {
                    prioritySelect.set('value', ' ');
                }
                if(userLevel=="TransScheduler") {
                     //Check priority override property
                     dojo.request.xhr("/workassign/getPriorityOverrideStatus.wa", {
                         handleAs: "text"
                     }).then(function(data){
                      if (data.indexOf("false") > -1) {
                          dijit.byId('prioritySelect').set('disabled',true);
                      }
                     }, function(err){
                        // Handle the error condition
                        alert("error: " + err);
                     }, function(evt){
                       // Handle a progress event from the request if the
                       // browser supports XHR2
                     });
                }
            }

       //Fetches and populate data
          transModeStore.fetch({query: {}, onBegin: transSizeMode, start: 0, count: 0});
          transTypeStore.fetch({query: {}, onComplete: fillTypes});
          priorityModeStore.fetch({query: {}, onBegin: prioritySizeMode, start: 0, count: 0});
          locStore.fetch({query: {}, onBegin: sizeLocs, start: 0, count: 0});

      //show the dialog
      dijit.byId("editDialog").show();
} //end edit_button_pressed


function setAutoPriority() {
    var params = "";
    if (dijit.byId("fromUnitSelect")) {
        params = params + "&FROMUNIT=" + dijit.byId("fromUnitSelect").get("value");
    }
    if (dijit.byId("toUnitSelect")) {
        params = params + "&TOUNIT=" + dijit.byId("toUnitSelect").get("value");
    }
    if (dijit.byId("fromSelect")) {
        params = params + "&FROMLOCATION=" + dijit.byId("fromSelect").get("value");
    }
    if (dijit.byId("toSelect")) {
        params = params + "&TOLOCATION=" + dijit.byId("toSelect").get("value");
    }
    if (dijit.byId("typeSelect")) {
        params = params + "&TYPE=" + dijit.byId("typeSelect").get("value");
    }

    dojo.request.xhr("getHighestPriority.URL?NUM=0" + params, {
                handleAs: "text"
            }).then(function(data){
                if (dijit.byId("prioritySelect")) {
                    dijit.byId("prioritySelect").set('value', data);
                }
            }, function(err){
                // Handle the error condition
                alert("error: " + err);
            }, function(evt){
               // Handle a progress event from the request if the
               // browser supports XHR2
            });
}

function setAutoTransporters() {
    var params = "";
    if (dijit.byId("typeSelect")) {
        params = params + "TYPES=" + dijit.byId("typeSelect").get("value");
    }
    dojo.request.xhr("getHighestNum.url?" + params, {
                handleAs: "text"
            }).then(function(data){
                if (dijit.byId("numTransSelect")) {
                    dijit.byId("numTransSelect").set('value', data);
                }
            }, function(err){
                // Handle the error condition
                alert("error: " + err);
            }, function(evt){
               // Handle a progress event from the request if the
               // browser supports XHR2
            });
}
```

As you can see I have fetches that call the XmlStores and select what should be selected in the individual dijits when applicable.  The problem functions for me are the setAutoPriority() and setAutoTransporters().  I could easily pass a variable to those functions to tell it whether or not it was the first load...or even wrap their call in an if statement.  I just can't figure out how to tell that everything (populating the dijits with data and set their value) has happened.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Nothing I've come up with has worked so far.  And just FYI, depending on the data from the grid row selected, not every one of those dijits will change/have data selected every time...which muddies the water even more.

Comment: did you try to add a ```onComplete``` hook to the ```locStore.fetch``` ?

Comment: I have tried that actually. I feel like what might work...I just don't know how to actually implement it, is to put the 4 fetches into a deferred list.  The problem is, they have a mixture of onBegin and onCompletes....and even then I don't know if I can determine if everything that is kicked off when running them (transSizeMode, fillTypes, prioritySizeMode, and sizeLocs) has actually completed.

Comment: just a raw idea: assuming you have the a closure variable ```isReady:false``` and 4 Deferred (on closure level as well). You wrap the 4 deferred i na promise/all wich set ```isReady = true``` when resolved. Then in each of the 4 ```onComplete``` you resolve one Deferred. ```isReady``` will be ```true``` when all are completed.

Comment: I don't know if it's just this morning or what, but I'm not really following...  Is the onComplete on a fetch going to wait until the onBegin function is completed? I was under the assumption that it wouldn't...it would just wait for the fetch itself to be complete.  Also, I already have an onComplete on the transTypeStore.fetch. Not sure how that would work.  If you could give me a snippet of the structure you're describing, it might be exactly what I'm needing...I just can't seem to wrap my head around it this morning..

Comment: It all run synchronously (see https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/data/util/simpleFetch.js#L43). So onBegin first, then onComplete. I will try to give you a little snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,
this is just a draft idea:

- i cannot test it
- it is dirty (there are better ways of doing)

But the general idea is there.
Core part of the idea are the first 4 lines of code.

```js
var fetchDone = 0;

function isReady() {
  return fetchDone >= 4; //the amount of fetch you have bellow
}

function edit_button_pressed() {
    //Javascript that creates the boxes
    //begin From Location

    //reset the counter
    fetchDone = 0;

    dojo.byId("fromSelector").innerHTML = "";
    var fromSelector = dojo.byId("fromSelector");
    var locStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
      url: 'getlocations.url',
      label: 'label',
      keyAttribute: 'id'
    });

    function sizeLocs(size, request) {
        var requests = size;
        if (requests > 0) {
          //from
          var fromSelect = new dijit.form.Select({
            name: "fromSelect",
            id: "fromSelect",
            store: locStore,
            style: "width: 200px;",
            labelAttr: "label"
          }).placeAt(fromSelector);
          fromSelect.startup();
          fromSelect.addOption({
            label: '--Select a Loc--',
            value: ' '
          });
          if (transFromLoc.length > 0) {
            fromSelect.set('value', transFromLoc);
          } else {
            fromSelect.set('value', ' ');
          }
          if (disableBecauseStarted) {
            fromSelect.set('disabled', 'disabled');
          }
          fromSelect.on("change", function() {
            if ((String(fromSelect.value) != String(defaultOrigination)) || disableBecauseStarted) {
              dijit.byId('fromUnitSelect').set('disabled', 'disabled');
              dijit.byId('fromRoomSelect').set('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
              dijit.byId('fromUnitSelect').set('disabled', false);
              dijit.byId('fromRoomSelect').set('disabled', false);
            }
            setAutoPriority();
          })
        }
      }
      //end from location
      //Units Select
    var unitStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
      url: 'getUnits.url',
      label: 'label',
      keyAttribute: 'id'
    });
    //from
    var fromUnitSelect = new dijit.form.Select({
      name: "fromUnitSelect",
      id: "fromUnitSelect",
      store: unitStore,
      style: "width: 150px;",
      labelAttr: "label"
    }).placeAt(dojo.byId('fromUnitSelector'));
    fromUnitSelect.startup();
    fromUnitSelect.set('disabled', 'disabled');
    fromUnitSelect.addOption({
      label: '--Unit--',
      value: ' '
    });
    if (transFromUnit.length > 0) {
      fromUnitSelect.set('value', transFromUnit);
    } else {
      fromUnitSelect.set('value', ' ');
    }
    fromUnitSelect.on("change", function() {
        dijit.byId('fromRoomSelect').destroy();
        var fromRoomStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
          url: 'getRooms.url?UNIT=' + this.value,
          label: 'label',
          keyAttribute: 'id'
        });
        var fromRoomSelect = new dijit.form.Select({
          name: "fromRoomSelect",
          id: "fromRoomSelect",
          store: fromRoomStore,
          style: "width: 150px;",
          labelAttr: "label"
        }).placeAt(dojo.byId('fromRoomSelector'));
        fromRoomSelect.startup();
        fromRoomSelect.addOption({
          label: '--Select a Room--',
          value: ' '
        });
        if (transFromRoom.length > 0) {
          fromRoomSelect.set('value', transFromRoom);
        } else {
          fromRoomSelect.set('value', ' ');
        }
        if (String(dijit.byId('fromSelect').value) != String(defaultOrigination)) {
          dijit.byId('fromUnitSelect').set('disabled', 'disabled');
          dijit.byId('fromRoomSelect').set('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
          dijit.byId('fromUnitSelect').set('disabled', false);
          dijit.byId('fromRoomSelect').set('disabled', false);
        }
        if (dijit.byId('patientSelect') != null && String(dijit.byId('patientSelect').value).length > 1) {
          var patientDataStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
            url: 'getPatient.url?MRN=' + String(dijit.byId('patientSelect').value),
            rootItem: "patient"
          });
          var getPat = function(items, request) {
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
              var item = items[i];
              var assignedRoom = String(patientDataStore.getValue(item, "assignedRoom"));
              var reservationRoom = String(patientDataStore.getValue(item, "roomReservationRoom"));
            }
            if (reservationRoom.length > 0) {
              setAssToRoom(reservationRoom);
              setAssRoom(assignedRoom);
            } else {
              setAssToRoom(assignedRoom);
              setAssRoom(assignedRoom);
            }
          }
          var request = patientDataStore.fetch({
            query: {},
            onComplete: getPat
          });
        }
        setAutoPriority();
      })
      //Begin Modes
    dojo.byId("createModeSelector").innerHTML = "";
    var createModeSelector = dojo.byId("createModeSelector");
    var transModeStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
      url: '/workassign/getTransModes.wa',
      label: 'label',
      keyAttribute: 'id'
    });

    function transSizeMode(size, request) {
      var requests = size;
      var modeSelect = "";
      if (requests > 0) {
        createModeSelect = new dijit.form.Select({
          name: "createModeSelect",
          id: "createModeSelect",
          store: transModeStore,
          style: "width: 200px;",
          labelAttr: "label"
        }).placeAt(createModeSelector);
        createModeSelect.startup();
        createModeSelect.addOption({
          label: '--Select a Mode--',
          value: ' '
        });
      }
    }
    transModeStore.fetch({
      query: {},
      onBegin: transSizeMode,
      start: 0,
      count: 0
    });
    //End Modes
    //Begin Types
    dojo.byId("typeSelector").innerHTML = "";
    var typeSelector = dojo.byId("typeSelector");
    var transTypeStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
      url: 'getType.url',
      label: 'label',
      keyAttribute: 'id'
    });
    var typeSel = new dijit.form.MultiSelect({
      name: 'typeSelect',
      id: 'typeSelect',
      style: 'width: 200px; font-size: 18px;'
    }).placeAt(typeSelector);
    var fillTypes = function(items, request) {
      dojo.forEach(items, function(item) {
        var c = dojo.doc.createElement('option');
        c.innerHTML = transTypeStore.getValue(item, "label");
        c.value = transTypeStore.getValue(item, "id");
        typeSelect.appendChild(c);
      })
      if (transType.length > 0) {
        var transArray = transType.split(",");
        typeSel.set('value', transArray);
      } else {
        typeSel.set("value", " ");
      }
    }
    typeSel.on("change", function() {
      setAutoPriority();
      setAutoTransporters();
    })
    typeSel.startup();
    //End Types
    dojo.byId("prioritySelector").innerHTML = "";
    var prioritySelector = dojo.byId("prioritySelector");
    var priorityModeStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
      url: 'getPriorities.url',
      label: 'label',
      keyAttribute: 'id'
    });

    function prioritySizeMode(size, request) {
      var requests = size;
      var modeSelect = "";
      if (requests > 0) {
        prioritySelect = new dijit.form.Select({
          name: "prioritySelect",
          id: "prioritySelect",
          store: priorityModeStore,
          style: "width: 200px;",
          labelAttr: "label"
        }).placeAt(prioritySelector);
        prioritySelect.startup();
        prioritySelect.addOption({
          label: '--Select a Priority--',
          value: ' '
        });
      }
      if (priorityType.length > 0) {
        prioritySelect.set('value', priorityType);
      } else {
        prioritySelect.set('value', ' ');
      }
      if (userLevel == "TransScheduler") {
        //Check priority override property
        dojo.request.xhr("/workassign/getPriorityOverrideStatus.wa", {
          handleAs: "text"
        }).then(function(data) {
          if (data.indexOf("false") > -1) {
            dijit.byId('prioritySelect').set('disabled', true);
          }
        }, function(err) {
          // Handle the error condition
          alert("error: " + err);
        }, function(evt) {
          // Handle a progress event from the request if the
          // browser supports XHR2
        });
      }
    }

    var onFetchComplete = function() {
      fetchDone++;
    };

    //Fetches and populate data
    transModeStore.fetch({
      query: {},
      onBegin: transSizeMode,
      onComplete: onFetchComplete,
      start: 0,
      count: 0
    });
    transTypeStore.fetch({
      query: {},
      onComplete: function() {
        onFetchComplete();
        fillTypes.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    });
    priorityModeStore.fetch({
      query: {},
      onBegin: prioritySizeMode,
      onComplete: onFetchComplete,
      start: 0,
      count: 0
    });
    locStore.fetch({
      query: {},
      onBegin: sizeLocs,
      onComplete: onFetchComplete,
      start: 0,
      count: 0
    });
    //show the dialog
    dijit.byId("editDialog").show();
  } //end edit_button_pressed

function setAutoPriority() {
  if (!isReady()) {
    return;
  }
  var params = "";
  if (dijit.byId("fromUnitSelect")) {
    params = params + "&FROMUNIT=" + dijit.byId("fromUnitSelect").get("value");
  }
  if (dijit.byId("toUnitSelect")) {
    params = params + "&TOUNIT=" + dijit.byId("toUnitSelect").get("value");
  }
  if (dijit.byId("fromSelect")) {
    params = params + "&FROMLOCATION=" + dijit.byId("fromSelect").get("value");
  }
  if (dijit.byId("toSelect")) {
    params = params + "&TOLOCATION=" + dijit.byId("toSelect").get("value");
  }
  if (dijit.byId("typeSelect")) {
    params = params + "&TYPE=" + dijit.byId("typeSelect").get("value");
  }
  dojo.request.xhr("getHighestPriority.URL?NUM=0" + params, {
    handleAs: "text"
  }).then(function(data) {
    if (dijit.byId("prioritySelect")) {
      dijit.byId("prioritySelect").set('value', data);
    }
  }, function(err) {
    // Handle the error condition
    alert("error: " + err);
  }, function(evt) {
    // Handle a progress event from the request if the
    // browser supports XHR2
  });
}

function setAutoTransporters() {
  if (!isReady()) {
    return;
  }
  var params = "";
  if (dijit.byId("typeSelect")) {
    params = params + "TYPES=" + dijit.byId("typeSelect").get("value");
  }
  dojo.request.xhr("getHighestNum.url?" + params, {
    handleAs: "text"
  }).then(function(data) {
    if (dijit.byId("numTransSelect")) {
      dijit.byId("numTransSelect").set('value', data);
    }
  }, function(err) {
    // Handle the error condition
    alert("error: " + err);
  }, function(evt) {
    // Handle a progress event from the request if the
    // browser supports XHR2
  });
}
```

Comment: I haven't actually implemented this yet, but this is what I was looking for. Thank you.